# json php example

Tags: php, json

I'm using a rest-api using php. Can someone tell me how to represent the below JSON format using php? The rest api requires this format to perform filtering.

--data-urlencode 'where={"post":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"8TOXdXf3tz"}}' \

Comment: Show some attempts you made. The answers present should give you enough hints. Don't ask to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_decode that string for the exact array that will result in, but yip and array of arrays...

```
$a = json_decode('{"post":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"8TOXdXf3tz"}}',true);
```

result:

```
    array(1) {
      ["post"] => array(3) {
        ["__type"] => string(7) "Pointer"
        ["className"] => string(4) "Post"
        ["objectId"] => string(10) "8TOXdXf3tz"
      }
    }
```

So writing as an array in PHP:

```
$thing = array(
    "post" => array(
        "__Type" => "Pointer",
        "className" => "Post",
        "objectId" =>> "9878076"
    );
);
```

Then json_encode would re-create the json...

Answer (score 2):

You can just create the array using PHP and then use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to create the JSON format.